# Lamp should only illuminate certain objects

Tags: objects, light, lighting

is it possible that a lamp only illuminates a certain object? All other objects should not be influenced by the lamp.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that it's only possible by the Compositor for the moment

Comment: Hmm ok. But is that also possible if the object is to be illuminated normally by all other lights, just not by a certain light?

Comment: it looks like it's the same, you can do that with the Compositor, if you know how it works

Comment: Unfortunately not. I haven't found anything about it on the Internet, but otherwise I can look again..

Comment: watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_SfxlD5YTg

Comment: Thank you moonboots!